# Determining dependencies on a javascript file in an MVC 5 application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Other than searching for keywords across the project files, is there a more deterministic way to find dependencies of a particular javascript library in an MVC project?

I should add that I'm supporting an already existing application that's been handed down over the years and gone through several technology changes.

Comment: Use the NuGet package manager.  If there's a package for the library then you'll see all the dependencies there.  If not you should be able to get it from the library in question's website.

Comment: @archer, sorry I went on a little mini-rant there. So even if there are no other nuget package dependencies, how can I determine other than searching for "foo.js" or any of the various other files in the package is used directly by the application? If text search is the only way, then so be it. It just isn't awesome.

Comment: The problem you face is that even by searching for "foo.js" you don't know what results you'll get.  For example, you may have had a developer work on the same project 5 years ago who made a Javascript library for directly querying a MySql database and decided to call it jQuery.  Unless you can find a specific list of dependencies from the authors then you can't find out without simply trying it and fixing what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that a text search is the best way as of now.

For text searching, I am used the VS Find in Files with regular expressions.

**Example:**
To find all variants of popper library which consists of

```
 popper-utils.js
 popper-utils.min.js
 popper.js
 popper.min.js
```

Use: \bpopper.\w+.js\b

The options in the Visual Studio Find in Files look like this.
[image]